# The type or namespace name PagedListRenderOptions could not be found

Tags: c#, pagination, asp.net-core-mvc

How to fix this? I included X.PagedList.Mvc.Core" Version="7.6.0"

```cs
<p>Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount</p>

@Html.PagedListPager(
(X.PagedList.IPagedList)ViewBag.OnePageOfProducts, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page = page }),
new PagedListRenderOptions { LiElementClasses = new string[] { "page-item" },
PageClasses = new string[] { "page-link" }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding below statement to your cshtml to fix the issue :

```
@using X.PagedList.Mvc.Common;
```

Reference github issue : https://github.com/dncuug/X.PagedList/issues/150

Comment: @using X.PagedList.Mvc.Core.Common worked for me

Answer (score 2):

In my Case this is What Worked

```
@using X.PagedList.Web.Common;
```